# Bluefish: open files on start that were open before

Tags: bluefish

how can I make Bluefish open the files that were open when I closed it on start? I can't find any option for that ...

K

Comment: This isn't really related to Ubuntu. You'd find an answer more easily in the documentation or on the forums and mailing lists of the Bluefish project.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution myself:

- create a project
- save it
- change the command to run bluefish (eg. bluefish.desktop) to "bluefish -c /absolute/path/to/project-file.bproject %F"